# Confusing Mypy Type Inspection in PyCharm and Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, pycharm, mypy

I am trying to understand type hints in python 3.6. I am using PyCharm with the [mypy plugin](https://github.com/leinardi/mypy-pycharm). I read [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), so I thought I had a fairly good understanding of how type annotations work.

Function and method annotations work as expected for the most part. Annotations for individual variables, however, make me doubt whether I really understood the idea.

Take the following example:

```python
b: Tuple[str, int] = 4
a: Tuple[str, int] = "s", 4
```

Here I expected that `a` passes type check and `b` does not. Unfortunately, mypy says the opposite: `b` passes but `a` does not.

[image: type error]

PyCharm's inbuilt type checker does not indicate anything, which is strange as well as it works as expected with the types of parameters and return values for functions and methods.

**Did I understand something wrong or is this some sort of bug?** Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately PyCharm does not support type checking in assignments, please vote for the corresponding [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24832).

Comment: It seems that you've also run into a bug in mypy -- or rather, a bug in [typed_ast](https://github.com/python/typed_ast), the library mypy uses to parse Python code. It seems that typed_ast is unhappy with expressions of the form `a: SomeType = 1, 2` -- you need to add parens and do `a: SomeType = (1, 2)` instead. (This also explains why mypy isn't complaining about the assignment to variable `b` -- mypy will quit early without performing type analysis if the parser says the code has some syntax error.) I recommend filing a bug report on the typed_ast issue tracker and adding parens for now.